# Application hangs on drawing multiple shapes in surfaceview in android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am working on drawing application like vector drawing, And I am using `surfaceview` to draw shapes. I am adding new shapes in the `list`. then I am using `postInvalidate()`. but when i am having more shapes objects then my Application Hangs.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            canvas.drawColor(getColor());
            Iterator<MyShape> drawableObject = objectsToDraw.iterator();
            while (drawableObject.hasNext()) {
                MyShape value = drawableObject.next();
                value.draw(canvas, value.getPaint());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void AddShapeOffline(MyShape shape) {
    objectsToDraw.add(shape);
    postInvalidate();
}
```

Any one please suggest me what am i doing wrong????

Comment: Where does it hang?  (Attach DDMS or a debugger and check where it's stuck.)

Comment: I have attached the device and searched in the DDMS but it does not show any error

Comment: In the DDMS Threads tab (with thread updates enabled), double-click on the thread that is hung.  This will show the current stack trace.  Or, connect a debugger and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks fadden for help.